# Devise overrides my request params when user is logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using request params in my application to transfer information from other websites.
The request looks like:

```
myapp.com/users/sign_up?customer=somevalue
```

Once a user isn’t logged in, everything works fine and I am able to retrieve these params in my registrations controller (I have overridden Devise's controller). I get them using:

```
customer_key = params[:customer]
```

Once the user is already logged in, I cant retrieve these params and I suspect Devise has modified them for me. The "post-login" params are:

```
{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"users", "id"=>"my-user"}
```

(this was taken from my users controller)

My question is - How can I retrieve these params when the user is logged in in my users controller?

Comment: Are you trying to capture the query parameter in signup link on user profile page? It would be much better if you can describe the actual user flow.

Comment: Sure. Currently we have a "special link" that we provide each one our customers so we can know where each one of our users has arrived from. Users can arrive from 2 or more different customers, and wewant to associate these users to both/all. The scenario I am trying to solve is: Once a user is logged in (and has already arrived from customer A), if he clicks on the link in Customer B - I cannot capture the params information to associate to his account

Comment: I still do not understand the problem completely. Does the link points to a authenticated area and the issue arises when user is not logged in? or its the other way around or something else? My best guess is that link is to authenticated user area and after login, you loose the actual parameter. If that is the case then you either need to pass on the parameter in redirect or store it in session to be used later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to create the `require_no_authentication` method in your overridden registrations controller.

`Devise::Registration` controller have this before filter `prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create, :cancel ]`

that checks if the user is logged in or not and if he is it redirects to the `after_sign_in_path`

as noted here

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L96

Good luck!